# How to put a covariate into the linear-mixed effects model?

Tags: r, mixed-model

In my linear-fixed effect model, I have two fixed factors "Fix-1" and "Fix-2", and a random factor "Ran". I think the continuous factor "Cov" may influence the dependent, and this influence is mainly works on "Fix-1". Now my R code of this model is:

```
Dependent ~ Fix-1 * Fix-2 + (1 + Fix-1 + Fix-2|Ran)
```

How can I put the covariate "Cov"?

Comment: If your question is just about R code it's likely to be seen as off topic. If it can be written either as a primarily statistics question or generalized to relate to consider the approach of adding covariates to a mixed model, or to how to add such a term to a model written in the Wilkinson & Rogers style of model formula ( Wilkinson G.N., and Rogers C.E. (1973). "Symbolic Description of Factorial Models for Analysis of Variance." Applied Statistics, 22, 392–399) - which R implements a version of - then that might be okay.

Comment: @Glen_b I think there is an important statistical question here since `Cov` may either be a mediator or a confounder which require different modelling.

Comment: @Robert Indeed -- but then the question should be rephrased (and as far as possible, by the OP) so that it actually asks that question. I suggest that as a general rule questions should ask the question that the answer gives before the answer is given. It still reads like a computing question.

Answer (score 5):

If I have understood your question correctly, there are really only 2 variables of interest here, `Cov` and `Fix-1`.  According to your theory, `Cov` is a cause of `Fix-1`. So, the key question is whether `Cov` is a cause, or a proxy for a cause, of the dependent variable too. If it is, then `Cov` is a confounder, and you can add it to the model as:

`Dependent ~ Fix-1 * Fix-2 + Cov + (1 + Fix-1 + Fix-2|Ran)`

or possibly (if supported by theory and the data):

`Dependent ~ Fix-1 * Fix-2 + Cov + (1 + Cov + Fix-1 + Fix-2|Ran)`

However, if `Cov` is NOT a cause, or a proxy for a cause, of the dependent variable, then `Fix-1` is a mediator, and should not be included in a model with `Fix-1` otherwise the reversal paradox may be invoked (Tu et al 2008), and so your model would be:

`Dependent ~ Fix-2 + Cov + (1 + Fix-2|Ran)`

Of course in this case you may instead wish to retain `Fix-1` and çontinue without `Cov`.

Tu, Yu-Kang, David Gunnell, and Mark S. Gilthorpe. *"Simpson's Paradox, Lord's Paradox, and Suppression Effects are the same phenomenon–the reversal paradox."* Emerging Themes in Epidemiology 5.1 (2008)